# Sort a column string according to only a part of that

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string with several column and different contents. In each row we have date and time. I am going to sort it by date time. My string is as following:

```
1905/04/25        14:01:00    27.67    56.03    0      5.8    AMB  
1907/07/04        09:12:00    27.18    56.28    0      6      AMB                                                  
1905/06/19        01:27:00    29.89    59.98    0      6.8    AMB                                                                                                     
1909/10/27        18:45:00    30.09    57.58    0      5.5    AMB
1902/07/09        03:38:00    27.08    56.34    0      6.4    AMB                                                   
1903/01/14        02:46:00    24       64       0      5.5    BS
```

What I expected:

```
1902/07/09        03:38:00    27.08    56.34    0      6.4    AMB                                                   
1903/01/14        02:46:00    24       64       0      5.5    BS                                                    
1905/04/25        14:01:00    27.67    56.03    0      5.8    AMB                                                   
1905/06/19        01:27:00    29.89    59.98    0      6.8    AMB                                                   
1907/07/04        09:12:00    27.18    56.28    0      6      AMB                                                   
1909/10/27        18:45:00    30.09    57.58    0      5.5    AMB
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings can be compared directly. For splitting them you can use `str.splitlines()`:

```
data = '''1905/04/25        14:01:00    27.67    56.03    0      5.8    AMB
1907/07/04        09:12:00    27.18    56.28    0      6      AMB
1905/06/19        01:27:00    29.89    59.98    0      6.8    AMB
1909/10/27        18:45:00    30.09    57.58    0      5.5    AMB
1902/07/09        03:38:00    27.08    56.34    0      6.4    AMB
1903/01/14        02:46:00    24       64       0      5.5    BS               '''


data = sorted(map(str.strip, data.splitlines()))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
['1902/07/09        03:38:00    27.08    56.34    0      6.4    AMB',
 '1903/01/14        02:46:00    24       64       0      5.5    BS',
 '1905/04/25        14:01:00    27.67    56.03    0      5.8    AMB',
 '1905/06/19        01:27:00    29.89    59.98    0      6.8    AMB',
 '1907/07/04        09:12:00    27.18    56.28    0      6      AMB',
 '1909/10/27        18:45:00    30.09    57.58    0      5.5    AMB']
```

Comment: Dear Andrej, Great, Thank you so much